# VBA Access 2010 DIR results in empty string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdExportTERNAME_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Me.MsgFld = "Please wait... exporting TERNAME file."

Dim expLoc As String
Dim xFile As String, myFile As String
Dim myFlag As Integer

expLoc = "I:\Investigative Names\"           ' PRD

xFile = Dir(expLoc & "NAME - ForUpload.txt", vbDirectory)
myFile = "NAME-ForUpload.txt"
myFlag = StrComp(xFile, myFile)
If myFlag <> -1 Then
   Kill expLoc & "NAME-ForUpload.txt"
End If

' Export text files for upload
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "SpecTERNAME", "qry_TERNAME", expLoc & "NAME-ForUpload.txt"

xFile = Dir(expLoc & "TNAME-ForUpload.txt")
myFile = "NAME-ForUpload.txt"
myFlag = StrComp(xFile, myFile)
If myFlag <> -1 Then
   GoTo ContinueProcessing1
Else
   MsgBox "The program was not able to export the NAME file for upload." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Please notify IS Department.", vbCritical, "ERROR MESSAGE BOX"
   GoTo exitRTN
End If

ContinueProcessing1:

exitRTN:

End Sub
```

So I have 2 more of these subroutines with different text files which work fine but this block of code doesn't find xFile, it return a empty string which causes the program to display the message box error.  I can't figure out why the same code with different text file works before it reaches this code.  The weird thing is it sometimes finds the correct xFile name in debug mode but not when run normally.  Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, you will have a hard time catching errors with `On Error Resume Next`. I would comment that before running any code that you are trying to debug. In this specific case, it might have something to do with the fact that you have inconsistent spacing between the "NAME" and "For Upload" in the different parts of your code. E.g., `NAME - ForUpload.txt` is not the same as `NAME-ForUpload.txt`, so `StrComp` will find that they are not the same.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt Sorry it was supposed to be like that, I fixed that issue but still seems to get kicked out into the msg box.  The weird thing is that even when the msg box is displayed, export of the file still completes.

Comment: Does your working code include `vbDirectory` as a parameter? [The Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dir-function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e) indicates that your `Dir` function call should be returning a directory name, which will fail when you feed it a file-specific path, resulting in an empty string. You should be able to confirm this by stepping through the code to see what is being stored in the `xpLoc` and `xFile` variables.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt Yes I have vbDirectory attribute in the Dir function.  Checking the ExpLoc variable shows "I:\Investigative Names" and myFile shows NAME-ForUpload.txt.  The line xFile = Dir(expLoc & "Name-ForUpload.txt", vbDirectory) shows empty string for xFile, that's where the issue is, because the check for myFlag results in -1 which gets kicked out the loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change `vbDirectory` to `vbNormal`?

Comment: @SmrtGrunt It still produces the same error.

Comment: Are `TNAME` and `NAME` the same? `Dir` can be used in a loop, returning new file names until exhausted (at which point it returns an empty string). So calling `Dir` twice for the same name will return an empty string the second time.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt So currently this application looks in I:\Investigative Names for the text files but I just copied those files on my local pc and did the test and successfully completed without any errors.  Do you think its like some sort of permissions issue? The weird thing is this program works on windows 7 pc and now that I upgraded to windows 10, this message shows up.

Comment: I think it's more likely to be an issue with the pathname to the I: drive, but I can't see any differences in the documentation for the `Dir` function between Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code works the same on your local directory both with and without an existing file? My guess is still that if it executes the `Kill` call, that causes the second `Dir` call to return an empty string.

Comment: Seems like changing the path to local and then back to I:\, fixed the issue.  Thanks for your suggestions